# Change the row values in pandas based on lookup

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe. One Contains actual data and second contains row index which i need to replace with some value.

Df1  : Input record

```
    A         B      record_id   record_type
0  12342345  10         011           H
1  65767454  20         012           I
2  78545343  30         013           I
3  43455467  40         014           I
```

Df2 :Information contains which row index need to change(e.g :here it is #)

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3  record_id
0        1        2        4     011
1        1        2        None  012
2        1        2        4     013
3        1        2        None  014
```

Output Result:

```
   A          B         record_id  record_type
0  #          #         011           #
1  #          #         012           I
2  #          #         013           #
3  #          #         014           I
```

So based on record_id lookup and want to change corresponding row index value.

Here (1    2  4  011)  present in Df2 contains information saying we want to modify row index first ,second and forth for particular record whose id is 011 from Df1.

So in output result we replace row value for record id 011 for row index 1,2,4 and populate value as #.

please suggest any other approach to do same in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can do some preprocessing to make life easier. Set the index to be `record_id` and then rename `column3` from df2 to be `record_type`. Now the dataframes have identical index and column names and makes for easy automatic alignment.

```
df1 = df1.set_index('record_id')
df2 = df2.set_index('record_id')
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Column3':'record_type'})
df2 = df2.replace('None', np.nan)
```

Then we can fill in missing values of df2 with d2 and then make all the original non-missing values '#'.

```
df2.fillna(df1).where(df2.isnull()).fillna('#')

          Column1 Column2 record_type
record_id                            
11              #       #           #
12              #       #           I
13              #       #           #
14              #       #           I
```

Comment: i want to do lookup based on record_id present in Df2.Df2 column1,column2,column3 contains index number for which i want to populate # value in Df1.(e.g :   [1        2        4     011]  row represent i want to modify row index first,second and forth for row id 011 in Df1).So input provided by you will directly replace # values which i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

> Here (1 2 4 011) present in Df2 contains information saying we want to modify row index first, second and forth for particular record whose id is 011 from Df1.

This makes no sense to me -- the row with `record_id` = 011 does not itself have further rows (of which you seem to want to choose the first, second, fourth). Please complete the output values with the exact results you expect.

In any case, I came across the same problem as in the title, and solved it like this:

Assuming you have a DataFrame `df` and three equally long vectors `rsel`, `csel` (for row/column selectors) and `val` (say, of length `N`), and would like to do the equivalent of

```
df.lookup(rsel, csel) = val
```

Then, the following code will work (at least) for `pandas v.0.23` and `python 3.6`, *assuming that `rsel` does not contain duplicates!*

**Warning:** this is not really suited for large datasets, because it initialises a full square matrix of the dimensions of shape `(N, N)`!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
def coalesce(df, ltr=True):
    if not ltr:
        df = df.iloc[:, ::-1] # flip left to right
    # use iloc as safeguard against non-unique column names
    list_of_series = [df.iloc[:, i] for i in range(len(df.columns))]
    # this is like a SQL coalesce
    return reduce(lambda interm, x: interm.combine_first(x), list_of_series)

# column names generally not unique!
square = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(val), index=rsel, columns=csel)
# np.diag creates 0s everywhere off-diagonal; set them to nan
square = square.where(np.diag([True] * len(rsel))) 
# assuming no duplicates in rsel; this is empty
upd = pd.DataFrame(index=rsel, columns=sorted(csel.unique()))
# collapse square into upd
upd = upd.apply(lambda col: coalesce(square[square.columns == col.name]))
# actually update values
df.update(upd)
```

PS. If you know that you only have strings as column names, then `square.filter(regex=col.name)` is much faster than `square[square.columns == col.name]`.